# How to set value in reactive form in angular?

Tags: angular, file-upload

I want to update user profile page in which I'm using patchValue for displaying data on onInit function when the component is initialized. What I've code is as follows:
I'm using patchValue because in response I have another data as well.

```
constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private amen: AmenService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUserDetails();

        this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            mobile: ['', Validators.required],
            user_img: ['']
        });
    }

    getUserDetails() {
        this.amen.getUserDetails(this.params).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.updateForm.patchValue(this.handleResponse(response));
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
            }
        );
    }

    handleResponse(response) {
        if (response.status === 1) {
            return response.responseData.UserData;
        }
        if (response.status === 0) {
            this.forAlertBox = true;
            this.msg = response.msg;
        }
    }

    preview(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0].name;
        }
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // return flow if form is invalid
        if (this.updateForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('user_img', this.selectedImage);
        formData.append('name', this.updateForm.get('name').value);
        formData.append('email', this.updateForm.get('email').value);
        formData.append('mobile', this.updateForm.get('mobile').value.internationalNumber);

        this.amen.updateUserProfile(formData).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleUpdateResponse(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('after update error', error);
            }
        );
    }

    handleUpdateResponse(response) {
        if (response.status === 1) {
            this.router.navigate(['edit-my-profile']);
        }

        if (response.status === 0) {
            this.forAlertBox = true;
            this.msg = response.msg;
        }
    }
```

Now, the problem is I can't set selectedImage variable to formData (instance of FormData()).
Please help!!

Comment: I got nothing in formData after append of each and every field

Answer (score 0):

First you have to select `user_img` controller, then patch value to just this controller.

```
this.updateForm.get('user_img').patchValue(...)
```

**append to FormData**

```
export function appendToDataForm(
  key: string, value: any | Array<any>, form: FormData = new FormData()
): FormData {

  for (const val of toArray(value)) {
    form.append(key, toBlob(val));
  }

  return form;
}

function toBlob(val: any): Blob {

  if (!istBlob(val)) {
    return new Blob([isString(val) ? val : JSON.stringify(val)], { type: 'application/json' });
  }

  return val;
}

export function toArray<T>(val: T | T[]): T[] {
  return Array.isArray(val) ? val : [val];
}

export function isBlob(val: any): boolean {
  return (val instanceof Blob) && typeof val === 'object';
}

export function isString(value: any): boolean {
  return typeof value === 'string';
}
```

Use it:

```
const form = new FormData();

appendToDataForm('file', this.selectedImage, form);
appendToDataForm('name', , this.updateForm.get('name').value, form );
appendToDataForm('email', , this.updateForm.get('email').value, form );
appendToDataForm('mobile', , this.updateForm.get('mobile').value.internationalNumber, form );
```

Comment: The problem is when I submit the form, formData doesn't append selectedImage in user_img.

Comment: if selected image is a File you have to create Blob Object and then append it to formData.

Comment: do you want example how to do it?

Comment: Please it helps me alot